# indexpath.row reset after 3 inside tableView heightForRowAt

Tags: swift, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath, indexpath

Hi like the title says the index.row never goes to 4 instead it starts over to [2,0]. My tableView has 5 rows. I don't know when it stopped working but I know for sure that it worked before I added the timeIndex row.

It's the "Enter Address Here" field which I'm having a problem displaying

```
let timeIndex = 2
let DateLocation = 1
let locationIndex = 4
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {



    if userPickedDate && indexPath.row == timeIndex {
        return 50
    }
    if userPickedDate && indexPath.row == DateLocation {

        return 0

    }
    print("The indexPath: \(indexPath)")
    if remindMeOnLocationSwitch.isOn && indexPath.row == locationIndex {
        return 100

    }
    if remindMeOnDay.isOn && indexPath.row == DateLocation{
        return 300
    } else if indexPath.row == DateLocation || indexPath.row == timeIndex || indexPath.row == locationIndex  {
        return 0
    }
    return 50

}
```

[image: tableview]

**Console output**

[image: Console output]

Comment: How many sections you have into your table view?

Comment: 3 one where the first textbox is, then one in the middle where the remindmeomday starts and the last one is the [today week todo] thing

Comment: i post a answer you can look hope you will understand why your indexPath never goes to 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem I forgot to update the number of rows inside the numberOfRowsInsideSection function

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    // Change from [1,4,1] to [1,5,1]
    let numberOfRowsInSection: [Int] = [1,5,1]
    var rows: Int = 0

    if section < numberOfRowsInSection.count {
        rows = numberOfRowsInSection[section]
    }

    return rows
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check what you have in numberOfRowsInSection

```
    func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
{
    if(section == 0){
    return 1
    }
    else if(section == 1){
        return 2
    }else{
        return 3
    }

}
```

Should be wrong number of rows being set in the numberOfRowsInSection

Answer (score 0):

Each section will have different number of rows.
that's why your indexPath never goes to 4.
[2,0] mean row number 0 in section 2.
you can check row according to section like this:-

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0{

    }else if indexPath.section == 1{

    }else if indexPath.section == 2{
         if indexPath.row == 0{
            // here is your fifth row return height for fifth row
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey I'm not sure if you miss understood me, but it's the "Enter address here" row I'm having a problem showing, not the segmentControll